# Weak law of large numbers but its bigger than $0$ and not $\epsilon$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $x_1 , x_2 , \dots , x_n$ be independent random variables with the same distribution.

Let's mark $$X_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

and let's mark $\mu$ as the mean of $X_n$.

I know that $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n-\mu> \epsilon) = 0$$ for any $\epsilon>0$ (based on the weak law of large numbers). I was wondering if this is also true: $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n-\mu> 0) = 0.$$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Let $(x_n)$be i.i.d. with a standard normal distribution. Then, $\mu =0, X_n \sim N(0,1/n)$ and $P(X_n-0 >0)=\frac 1 2$ for each $n$.

More generally, the conclusion fails for any symmetric continuous distrbition with finite mean.